# Why does my iPhone create contacts with a random photo?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, graphics, contacts

I have a strange issue on my iPhone 4 running 4.3.2, the device is jailbroken.

When I add a new contact, the contacts application seems to assign a random photo to newly created contacts. My phone syncs with mobile me so this is replicated across all my devices.

1. I create a new contact
2. I click done.
3. I view the contact and it has a random picture assigned to it.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Usually it's a memory allocation bug. What jailbreak did you use? Perhaps others have the same issue? If not, you might wipe your device and start over since the data structures are getting hosed in what appears to be a systematic way.

Comment: Are you syncing your contacts with anything? (e.g. Google, iCloud, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wiping the device and starting with this - it's usually corruption in the address book database - even on devices that haven't been jailbroken. You might have luck just starting new with that before a total restore.